# How to correctly add the src to printThis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, printthis

Whenever I add the  references in javascript it keeps saying that the references cannot be loaded. I have downloaded the packages and have them sitting in a file called Data/NGData/Dependencies/Packages.
I would have thought that the src would look like this

```
<script src="/Data/NGData/Dependencies/Packages/printThis.js"> </script>
```

But that doesn't work. Can anyone give me some pointers so that I can use the library.

EDIT: The error that I'm getting [image: The error that I'm getting]

Comment: what specific error are you getting? 404? Also I'm assuming it's a typo but every html attribute should be enclosed in double quotes. `<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: I just forgot to add them in for the example. I've included a picture of what the error is saying. This is me trying different path files

Comment: If you go to the network tab you'll see the HTTP error codes which are likely to be 404's. If this happens then either your paths are wrong (in the `src` attribute) or you are not serving the files to the webserver as static files.

Comment: Yeah, its a 404 error. I'd say the path is wrong but not sure how to rectify it

Comment: is the `Data` folder in the root of your webserver?

Comment: Yeah its in the root